#  into mysql database not working

Tags: php, utf-8, utf8mb4

I am trying to insert an emoji () into mysql database.

When I insert it from php code it inserts as ????.

And when I try to copy and paste it into phpmyadmin the following error occurs:

> `Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x8D' for column 'content' at row 1`

The column 'content' is long text.

Then I tried it with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` instead of `utf8_unicode_ci` collation but I still get the same result from php although it inserts correctly in phpmyadmin.

I have followed many tutorials online and made all the database changes suggested but I can't find an answer to my problem.

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Thank you gattsbr, changing from SET NAMES 'utf8' to SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' when connecting to the database did the trick!

Comment: @DanielOrmerod - That is 1 of about 4 steps to make things right.  You probably had the other steps already in place.

Comment: @Rick James - I had already done the other steps you are referring to before asking my question on here. The SET NAMES was the only thing I had missed.

Comment: @DanielOrmerod - Good.  My comment was more toward others reading this Q&A.  `SET NAMES` may fail for them, only because they have not (yet) done the other steps.